# Advice for planning long comic book arcs and subplots?

Tags: planning, comics, subplot

It's common in traditional superhero comics for there to be a number percolating subplots, that may be developed over one or several years' time. For example, a standard issue may have about 20 pages of the main climaxing current A plot, possibly 3 pages of developing subplot B, and maybe a single page of newly-introduced subplot C. (Something like that, as a very rough impression.) The subplots may then appear briefly in each sequential issue, or they may not be addressed again for several issues. Resolution may take years of time.

I've seen advice and formats from comic authors for how to write the script for a single issue, but I've never seen advice for planning out longer story arcs, how frequently and to what extent subplots are scheduled, or how far out in advance it's common to plan things. Is there something like a series bible, planned ahead for years? Or given that a single person is really running the scripts, is it acceptable to be mostly in the one author's head the whole time?

Are there any links or references to where professional comics authors have discussed or given advice on how this is planned, documented, and scheduled?